# how to do addition In Sql Server using dynamic generated field?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table called "Cart". Fields are :

- `CartId`
- `ClientId`
- `ProductId`
- `Qty`

Now i am joining this table with `ProductMaster` to get `ProductName` and `ProuctPrice`

```
select cc.CartId,cc.ProductId,pm.ProductName,cc.Qty,
        (pm.ProductPrice * cc.Qty) As SubTotal 
from ClientCart as cc 
    inner join ProductMaster as pm on cc.ProductId = pm.ProductId
```

Now I want to genrate `GrandTotal` using dynamic field `SubTotal`. How Can i do this?

Comment: Removed unrelated mysql tag

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as
(
select cc.CartId,cc.ProductId,pm.ProductName,cc.Qty,
        (pm.ProductPrice * cc.Qty) As SubTotal 
from ClientCart as cc 
    inner join ProductMaster as pm on cc.ProductId = pm.ProductId 
where cc.ClientId = @id
)
select *
from CTE
union
select null,null, null,null, sum(SubTotal) -- this is a grand total of all sub totals
from CTE
```

It's not the proper Rollup method, but neither is yours so this will work fine

Comment: this is not generating separate grandtotal field.!

Comment: @DevKriya Edit your question to explain better. Also, SQL has columns, even in results. Fields are not an SQL object, hence the interpretation as a row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select subtable.CartId, sum(subtable.SubTotal)
from (
select cc.CartId,cc.ProductId,pm.ProductName,cc.Qty,
        (pm.ProductPrice * cc.Qty) As SubTotal 
from ClientCart as cc 
inner join ProductMaster as pm on cc.ProductId = pm.ProductId 
where cc.ClientId = @id ) subtable
group by subtable.CartId;
```